# .net adapter for websphere process server

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, websphere, adapter, websphere-6.1

We are looking at ways to integrate WebSphere (6.1.0.17) with .net.

Is there a native adapter or do we need to go via a web service call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have got an answer from IBM on this. There is no adapter for .net, so the way to integrate is via web services.